# XAML Control / Layouts Image Sliding for windows 10

Tags: xaml, windows-mobile, windows-10, win-universal-app

currently i'm developing an windows 10 uwp apps, and i'm getting trouble ini designing my apps

i'm planning to make some kind of a image slider or whatever it names, just like in the Store apps, on the top page. it looks like a banner slide or something.

but i hardly find it on tutorials anywhere in the internet nor in documentation.

i think and believe that this using a pivot, but i'm confuse how to style it. so if someone probably knows, how to achieve this, please kindly answer it.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must use FlipView control.

Please check the documentation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/flipview